# Why I can't scrape images inside a class or a div?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the images within a `div`, but everytime I try the output returns 'none' or just an empyt list. The issue just seems to happens when I try to scrape between a `div`, or a `class`. Even using different user-agents, `.find` or `.find_all` .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

abcde = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.gettyimages.com.br/fotos/randon', headers=abcde)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
check = soup.find_all('img', class_="GalleryItems-module__searchContent___DbMmK"})
print(check)
```

Comment: Is the code you shared the code of what *does* work? (i.e. grab all the images on the page?) Can you also share what you tried to grab images in a specific div?

Comment: This code doesnt work. I was just trying to acess anything inside a class but whatever site, or different classes I try to scrape, nothing works. The output just returns an empty list, even when in the div is full of images, links of paragraphs.

Comment: You're looking for images with the specific class ending in `DbMmK` - but that appears to be a postfix that's on none of the images on the page, so that makes sense. Also, it appears the document model is constructed after loading by running JavaScript, so you'll need to use something like `selenium` to even get the page you're after

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend to work with an api, while there is on https://developers.gettyimages.com/docs/

To answer your question concerning just images - Classes are not the best identifier cause often they are dynamic, also there is a gallery(fixed) and a mosaic view.

Simply select the `<article>` and its child `<img>` to get your goal:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.gettyimages.com.br/fotos/randon?assettype=image&sort=mostpopular&phrase=randon',
                 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
                )
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for e in soup.select('article img'):
    print(e.get('src'))
```

Output

```
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/randon-norway-picture-id974597088?k=20&m=974597088&s=612x612&w=0&h=EIwbJNzCld1tbU7rTyt42pie2yCEk5z4e6L6Z4kWhdo=
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/caption-patrick-roanhouse-a-266-member-chats-about-some-software-on-picture-id97112678?k=20&m=97112678&s=612x612&w=0&h=zmwqIlVv2f-M9Vz_qcpITPzj-3SON99G3P69h69J5Gs=
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/12th-and-f-streets-nw-washington-dc-pedestrians-teofila-randon-left-picture-id97102402?k=20&m=97102402&s=612x612&w=0&h=potzNUgMo3gKab5eS_pwyNggS2YGn6sCnDQYxdGUHqc=
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/randon-perdue-kari-barnhart-attend-the-other-nashville-society-one-picture-id969787702?k=20&m=969787702&s=612x612&w=0&h=kcaYmOKruLb57Vqga68xvEZB1V12wSPPYkC6GdvXO18=
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/death-of-duguesclin-to-chateauneuf-de-randon-july-13-1380-during-the-picture-id959538894?k=20&m=959538894&s=612x612&w=0&h=lx3DHDSf3kBc_h-O2kjR2D6UYDjPPvhn8xJ_KM0cmMc=
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/ski-de-randone-a-saintefoy-au-dessus-du-couloir-de-la-croix-savoie-mr-picture-id945817638?k=20&m=945817638&s=612x612&w=0&h=fRd3M2KCa5dd0z8ePnPw2IkAKhXYJpuCFuUTz7jpVPU=
...
```